# Compare two tables amount with respect to priortization of FundType

Tags: sql-server, query

I have two tables one is PaymentDetail and another is Ledger

[image]

Here i want to prioritize paymodetype in manner that cash should be considered first for 
R,A and then I FundType, then Credit Card, then DD and then Cheque.

I want that amount received in cash should first be considered for R then A and lastly for I FundType.Another example
[image]

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0dd32/9) as well. Can it be solved by SQL only. I don't want to use Cursor.
**Edit:**
I have updated the [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0dd32/41) with what i have tried. I am trying to use join due to which multiple rows are obtained in my result with respect to Payment Detail. I want to span amount of one row of payment detail over Ledger then second row should be used.
How can i achieve that?
Result of current [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0dd32/41) is 
[image]

Comment: @SQLKiwi 1) Yes it is a realtime problem, The Paymodedetail has aprrox .5 million and Ledger has 1.1 Million rows.2) Can it be done using single query as i have posted my solution in sqlfiddle.3) Yes order of payment is guranteed to be R>A>I. 4)There Might be leftover but we will consider the amount which is realised means in paymentdetail satisfying Ledger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cannot think of a reasonable way to meet the requirement with a T-SQL non-cursor solution, so the following is a SQLCLR procedure that returns a result set.  The solution performs a single scan of each table (at most).  In a test with 500,000 Payment rows and 1,000,000 Ledger rows, it completed in 4.8 seconds with a warm buffer pool and 5.2 seconds from a cold start - including the time to display the 120,000 rows of results in SSMS.

The procedure uses the `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` permission set, so `ALTER DATABASE [name] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;` is the easiest way for testing (the database must also have a valid owner).  For deployment, you might prefer to sign it and grant the permission explicitly.  I was unable to upload this to SQL Fiddle as it has a limit of 8000 characters for DDL statements.

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [dbase]
FROM 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
WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MatchLedgerRecords]
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [dbase].[StoredProcedures].[MatchLedgerRecords];
```

Sample data reproduced from your SQL Fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PaymentDetail
(
    PaymentId   integer PRIMARY KEY,
    RecptNo     integer NOT NULL,
    Amount      float NOT NULL,
    PayModeType varchar(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Ledger
(
    LedgerId    integer PRIMARY KEY,
    Recptno     integer NOT NULL,
    FundType    char(1) NOT NULL,
    amount      float NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.PaymentDetail
    (PaymentId, RecptNo, Amount, PayModeType)
VALUES 
    (1, 1, 1000, 'Cash'),
    (2, 1, 3000, 'Cheque'),
    (3, 2, 4000, 'Cheque'),
    (4, 2, 1000, 'Cheque');

INSERT INTO dbo.Ledger
    (LedgerId, Recptno, FundType, amount)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'R', 500),
    (2, 1, 'A', 500),
    (3, 1, 'I', 1000),
    (4, 1, 'I', 1000),
    (5, 1, 'I', 1000),
    (6, 2, 'R', 2000),
    (7, 2, 'A', 1000),
    (8, 2, 'I', 2000);
```

Usage:

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[MatchLedgerRecords];
```

Output:

[image: Results]

Source code:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [SqlProcedure]
    public static void MatchLedgerRecords()
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder scb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        // Use a context connection to find the name of the server and current database
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context connection = true"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT @ServerName = @@SERVERNAME, @DatabaseName = DB_NAME()", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ServerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DatabaseName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Build a connection string
            scb.Enlist = false;
            scb.IntegratedSecurity = true;
            scb.DataSource = (string)cmd.Parameters[0].Value;
            scb.InitialCatalog = (string)cmd.Parameters[1].Value;
        }

        // Non-context-connections
        using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(scb.ConnectionString), conn2 = new SqlConnection(scb.ConnectionString))
        {
            conn1.Open();
            conn2.Open();

            // Commands to read the two tables in the required order
            SqlCommand paymentCommand = new SqlCommand(
                @"
                SELECT 
                    PaymentID, 
                    RecptNo,
                    Amount, 
                    PayModeType 
                FROM dbo.PaymentDetail 
                ORDER BY 
                    PaymentID;", conn1);

            SqlCommand ledgerCommand = new SqlCommand(
                @"
                SELECT
                    LedgerID, 
                    RecptNo, 
                    FundType, 
                    Amount 
                FROM dbo.Ledger 
                ORDER BY 
                    LedgerID;", conn2);

            // Avoid default 30 second timeout
            paymentCommand.CommandTimeout = 300;
            ledgerCommand.CommandTimeout = 300;

            // Shape of the results
            SqlMetaData[] smd = new SqlMetaData[] 
            {
                    new SqlMetaData("PaymentID", SqlDbType.Int),
                    new SqlMetaData("LedgerID", SqlDbType.Int),
                    new SqlMetaData("FundType", SqlDbType.Char, 1),
                    new SqlMetaData("Amount", SqlDbType.Float),
                    new SqlMetaData("PayModeType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)
            };

            SqlDataRecord sdr = new SqlDataRecord(smd);

            // Indicate start-of-results to SQL Server
            SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart(sdr);

            // Main algorithm
            using (SqlDataReader paymentReader = paymentCommand.ExecuteReader(), ledgerReader = ledgerCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (ledgerReader.Read() && paymentReader.Read())
                {
                    // Read the first ledger row column values
                    // (ordinal numbers are the column position from the original SELECT)
                    int LedgerID = ledgerReader.GetInt32(0);
                    int LedgerReceiptNo = ledgerReader.GetInt32(1);
                    string FundType = ledgerReader.GetString(2);
                    double LedgerAmount = ledgerReader.GetDouble(3);

                    // Read the first payment row column values
                    int PaymentID = paymentReader.GetInt32(0);
                    int PaymentReceiptNo = paymentReader.GetInt32(1);
                    double PaymentAmount = paymentReader.GetDouble(2);
                    string PayModeType = paymentReader.GetString(3);

                    // A modified merge join
                    while (true)
                    {
                        // Join on receipt number
                        if (LedgerReceiptNo == PaymentReceiptNo)
                        {
                            // If the current ledger amount can be allocated from the current payment
                            if (LedgerAmount <= PaymentAmount)
                            {
                                // Set result column values
                                sdr.SetInt32(0, PaymentID);
                                sdr.SetInt32(1, LedgerID);
                                sdr.SetString(2, FundType);
                                sdr.SetDouble(3, LedgerAmount);
                                sdr.SetString(4, PayModeType);

                                // Send a result row
                                SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(sdr);

                                // Subtract the allocated amount from the payment amount available
                                PaymentAmount -= LedgerAmount;

                                // Next ledger record
                                if (!ledgerReader.Read()) break;

                                // Read the ledger record's columns
                                LedgerID = ledgerReader.GetInt32(0);
                                LedgerReceiptNo = ledgerReader.GetInt32(1);
                                FundType = ledgerReader.GetString(2);
                                LedgerAmount = ledgerReader.GetDouble(3);
                            }
                            // Ledger amount is greater than the payment amount remaining
                            else
                            {
                                // Return a row for the remaining payment amount (if non-zero)
                                if (PaymentAmount > 0)
                                {
                                    sdr.SetInt32(0, PaymentID);
                                    sdr.SetInt32(1, LedgerID);
                                    sdr.SetString(2, FundType);
                                    sdr.SetDouble(3, PaymentAmount);
                                    sdr.SetString(4, PayModeType);

                                    SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(sdr);

                                    // Adjust the ledger amount
                                    LedgerAmount -= PaymentAmount;
                                }

                                // Read the next payment record
                                if (!paymentReader.Read()) break;

                                // Read the payment record columns
                                PaymentID = paymentReader.GetInt32(0);
                                PaymentReceiptNo = paymentReader.GetInt32(1);
                                PaymentAmount = paymentReader.GetDouble(2);
                                PayModeType = paymentReader.GetString(3);
                            }
                        }
                        // Receipt numbers do not currently match, payment behind ledger
                        else if (PaymentReceiptNo < LedgerReceiptNo)
                        {
                            // Read next payment record
                            if (!paymentReader.Read()) break;

                            // Read column values
                            PaymentID = paymentReader.GetInt32(0);
                            PaymentReceiptNo = paymentReader.GetInt32(1);
                            PaymentAmount = paymentReader.GetDouble(2);
                            PayModeType = paymentReader.GetString(3);
                        }
                        // Receipt numbers do not currently match, ledger behind payment
                        else
                        {
                            // Read next ledger record
                            if (!ledgerReader.Read()) break;

                            // Read column values
                            LedgerID = ledgerReader.GetInt32(0);
                            LedgerReceiptNo = ledgerReader.GetInt32(1);
                            FundType = ledgerReader.GetString(2);
                            LedgerAmount = ledgerReader.GetDouble(3);
                        }
                    // end while: Repeat until ledger or payment runs out of rows
                    }
                }
                // End of result set
                SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly the output you want, but you'll get some ideas. test at [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b987/3):

order the **`PaymentDetail`**:

```
; WITH LedgerSortOrder AS
    ( SELECT 1 AS SortOrder, 'R' AS FundType
    UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, 'A'
    UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, 'I'
    )     

, LedgerOrdered AS
    ( SELECT L.*
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY L.RecptNo 
                                 ORDER BY LSO.SortOrder, L.LedgerID )
               AS Rn
      FROM Ledger AS L
        JOIN LedgerSortOrder AS LSO
          ON LSO.FundType = L.FundType
    ) 

, LedgerCTE AS
    ( SELECT L1.RecptNo, L1.Amount, L1.FundType
           , SUM(L2.Amount) AS SumAmount
      FROM LedgerOrdered AS L1
        JOIN LedgerOrdered AS L2
          ON  L2.RecptNo = L1.RecptNo
          AND L2.Rn <= L1.Rn
      GROUP BY L1.RecptNo, L1.Rn, L1.Amount, L1.FundType
    )
```

order the **`Ledger`**:

```
, PaymentDetailSortOrder AS
    ( SELECT 1 AS SortOrder, 'Cash' AS PayModeType
    UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, 'Credit Card'
    UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, 'DD'
    UNION ALL
      SELECT 4, 'Cheque'
    )

, PaymentDetailOrdered AS
    ( SELECT P.*
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY P.RecptNo 
                                 ORDER BY PSO.SortOrder, P.PaymentID )
               AS Rn
      FROM PaymentDetail AS P
        JOIN PaymentDetailSortOrder AS PSO
          ON PSO.PayModeType = P.PayModeType 
    ) 

, PaymentDetailCTE AS
    ( SELECT P1.RecptNo, P1.PayModeType, P1.Amount
           , SUM(P2.Amount) AS SumAmount
      FROM PaymentDetailOrdered AS P1
        JOIN PaymentDetailOrdered AS P2
          ON  P2.RecptNo = P1.RecptNo
          AND P2.Rn <= P1.Rn
      GROUP BY P1.RecptNo, P1.Rn, P1.PayModeType, P1.Amount
    )
```

then join the two CTEs:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(P.RecptNo, L.RecptNo) AS RecptNo
  , L.FundType
  , L.Amount
  , P.PayModeType
  , COALESCE(L.SumAmount, P.SumAmount) AS SumAmount
FROM PaymentDetailCTE AS P
  FULL JOIN LedgerCTE AS L
    ON  L.RecptNo = P.RecptNo
    AND L.SumAmount = P.SumAmount
ORDER BY RecptNo, SumAmount ;
```

Comment: You have put a lot of effort, Its not exact but near by i have to work on this solution to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my better understanding of your requirements, I have updated my answer.  **It is not perfect.**  Specifically, it does not gracefully handle a payment that is larger than the last available ledger amount.  Feel free to modify to better suit your needs.

```
WITH PaymentCTE
(
    Recptno,
    LedgerAmount,
    FundType,
    PayModeType,
    RowNum,
    Amount,
    PaidAmount,
    AmountRemaining,
    Ordinal
)
AS
(
    SELECT
        MasterRecords.Recptno,
        MasterRecords.LedgerAmount,
        MasterRecords.FundType,
        MasterRecords.PayModeType,
        MasterRecords.RowNum,
        MasterRecords.Amount,
        CASE
            WHEN MasterRecords.LedgerAmount <= MasterRecords.Amount THEN MasterRecords.LedgerAmount
            ELSE MasterRecords.Amount
        END AS PaidAmount,
        MasterRecords.Amount -      
        CASE
            WHEN MasterRecords.LedgerAmount <= MasterRecords.Amount THEN MasterRecords.LedgerAmount
            ELSE MasterRecords.Amount
        END AS AmountRemaining,
        MasterRecords.Ordinal
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            pd.RecptNo,
            AllRecords.LedgerAmount,
            AllRecords.FundType,
            pd.PayModeType,
            ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER
            (
                PARTITION BY
                    pd.RecptNo,
                    pd.PaymentId
                ORDER BY
                    pd.RecptNo ASC,
                    AllRecords.Ordinal ASC          
            ) AS RowNum,
            AllRecords.Ordinal,
            pd.Amount

        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                TotalAmount.Recptno,
                TotalAmount.amount AS LedgerAmount,
                PaymentPriority.FundType,
                PaymentPriority.PayModeType,
                PaymentPriority.Ordinal
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT
                    'R' AS FundType,
                    'Cash' AS PayModeType,
                    1 AS Ordinal
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    'A' AS FundType,
                    'Cash' AS PayModeType,
                    2 AS Ordinal
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    'I' AS FundType,
                    'Cash' AS PayModeType,
                    3 AS Ordinal
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    'I' AS FundType,
                    'CreditCard' AS PayModeType,
                    4 AS Ordinal
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    'I' AS FundType,
                    'DD' AS PayModeType,
                    5 AS Ordinal
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    'I' AS FundType,
                    'Cheque' AS PayModeType,
                    6 AS Ordinal
            ) AS PaymentPriority

                INNER JOIN dbo.Ledger AS TotalAmount
                    ON PaymentPriority.FundType = TotalAmount.FundType
        ) AS AllRecords

            INNER JOIN dbo.PaymentDetail AS pd
                ON AllRecords.Recptno = pd.RecptNo
                AND AllRecords.PayModeType = pd.PayModeType
    ) AS MasterRecords

    WHERE MasterRecords.RowNum = 1  

    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        MasterRecords.Recptno,
        MasterRecords.LedgerAmount,
        MasterRecords.FundType,
        MasterRecords.PayModeType,
        MasterRecords.RowNum,
        pcte.AmountRemaining AS Amount,
        CASE
            WHEN MasterRecords.LedgerAmount <= pcte.AmountRemaining THEN MasterRecords.LedgerAmount
            ELSE pcte.AmountRemaining
        END AS PaidAmount,
        pcte.AmountRemaining -      
        CASE
            WHEN MasterRecords.LedgerAmount <= pcte.AmountRemaining THEN MasterRecords.LedgerAmount
            ELSE pcte.AmountRemaining
        END AS AmountRemaining,
        MasterRecords.Ordinal
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            pd.RecptNo,
            AllRecords.LedgerAmount,
            AllRecords.FundType,
            pd.PayModeType,
            ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER
            (
                PARTITION BY
                    pd.RecptNo,
                    pd.PaymentId
                ORDER BY
                    pd.RecptNo ASC,
                    AllRecords.Ordinal ASC          
            ) AS RowNum,
            AllRecords.Ordinal,
            pd.Amount

        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                TotalAmount.Recptno,
                TotalAmount.amount AS LedgerAmount,
                PaymentPriority.FundType,
                PaymentPriority.PayModeType,
                PaymentPriority.Ordinal
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT
                    'R' AS FundType,
                    'Cash' AS PayModeType,
                    1 AS Ordinal
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    'A' AS FundType,
                    'Cash' AS PayModeType,
                    2 AS Ordinal
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    'I' AS FundType,
                    'Cash' AS PayModeType,
                    3 AS Ordinal
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    'I' AS FundType,
                    'CreditCard' AS PayModeType,
                    4 AS Ordinal
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    'I' AS FundType,
                    'DD' AS PayModeType,
                    5 AS Ordinal
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    'I' AS FundType,
                    'Cheque' AS PayModeType,
                    6 AS Ordinal
            ) AS PaymentPriority

                INNER JOIN dbo.Ledger AS TotalAmount
                    ON PaymentPriority.FundType = TotalAmount.FundType
        ) AS AllRecords

            INNER JOIN dbo.PaymentDetail AS pd
                ON AllRecords.Recptno = pd.RecptNo
                AND AllRecords.PayModeType = pd.PayModeType

    ) AS MasterRecords

        INNER JOIN PaymentCTE AS pcte
            ON MasterRecords.RecptNo = pcte.Recptno
            AND MasterRecords.PayModeType = pcte.PayModeType

    WHERE MasterRecords.RowNum = pcte.RowNum + 1
)
SELECT
    PaymentCTE.Recptno,
    PaymentCTE.FundType,
    PaymentCTE.PayModeType, 
    PaymentCTE.PaidAmount
FROM PaymentCTE

WHERE PaymentCTE.PaidAmount > 0

ORDER BY
    PaymentCTE.Recptno ASC,
    PaymentCTE.RowNum ASC,
    PaymentCTE.Ordinal ASC;
```

Thanks for the interesting challenge.  Sorry I couldn't make it suit your needs 100%.  Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: I have updated SQLFiddle i have tried and the result i am obtaining, I want to eliminate the repetition of rows

Comment: Thanks for putting up your time, You have given interesting try. I am trying to work on it,I checked It skips some rows.